# Xcode and python and java

Tags: xcode, java, python

I just installed Xcode 4. Everything seemed fine, but then, after poking around, I found that the ability to create Python and Java (And probably more) projects was missing. I asked Apple in apple store chat (on their web site) and was told that Python and Java are supported. However, I can't find where to make a Python or Java project - only C based files (and some more miscellaneous files). Does anyone know how to make Java/Python based files/projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Xcode 4 does not support Java or python so I would be interested in seeing what the chat said. OSX does support both.

Xcode was never a very good IDE for java or python so I would always try to use something else (except if using PyObjc)

Look on Stack Overflow for suggestions of IDEs

IntelliJ/PyCharm and Eclipse work on OSX as do several others

Comment: I currently use Eclipse, I was just wondering what happened to the editors - I wonder whether there is still support for .py files and the like, even though you cannot make files for them on the computer. Coincidentally, do you know any good mac asp / ruby editors?

Answer (score 0):

TextMate is a good editor for Ruby and Python. Tons of bundle's can be added to make it fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed with Python support; just drop into the terminal:

`$ python —version`

`Python 2.7.1`

You can use Xcode’s editor to make .py files, etc.

Check out [Quick Python/Developer tips for OSX Lion](http://jessenoller.com/2011/07/30/quick-pythondeveloper-tips-for-osx-lion/) for more details.

Regarding Java, it’s not part of Lion, but that’s easy to fix—download [the runtime for Java SE 6 version 1.6.0_26](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1421) from Apple so you can run the programs you’ll be writing and possibly an IDE (like Eclipse) that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried Python in XCode, but I have successfully built Java projects with XCode 3. When I updated XCode to 3.2, they dropped the Java Templates. I just used Time Machine to get the templates back and added them to `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Project Templates/Java` and now I have my templates and it still compiles. I can't confirm if this works in XCode 4 but you can give it a try. I uploaded the templates if you don't have them and need to [download](http://www.filedropper.com/java-templates).

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'll get back to you on whether they work with Xcode 4.